# How do you load each mat-tab with a different datasource?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm new to Angular and having some issues trying to display different data for 3 mat-tabs.

I have a parent component and 3 child mat-table type components - I just want to fill each with the appropriate content.

The parent receives one object which I pass to the child component and parse into 3 separate arrays for display.

The child components are really just one "template" child table component that I'd like display on tab click with the relevant data - but it seems like once `dataSource` is set, I can't modify it for the next tab click.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="onTabChange($event)">
  <mat-tab label="INCOME">
    <app-table
      *ngIf="company"
      [company]="company"
      [dataSource]="incomeArray"></app-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="BALANCE">
    <app-table
      *ngIf="company"
      [company]="company"
      [dataSource]="balanceArray"></app-table>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="CASH">
    <app-table
      *ngIf="company"
      [company]="company"></app-table>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

where I'm passing `company` from the parent, and setting the arrays on `ngOnInit()` in the child component

I can see the arrays in the console log from the `app-table` child component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to modify data inside of the tabs and have the other tabs reflect changes made in other tabs, that will require a different approach. In this case you want to create a new service called DataService and then create an observable (i.e. subject or behaviorSubject) holding your dataSource array info inside of the DataService. Inside of each tab, subscribe to that observable for your dataSource. Whenever a value change is made, update the observable using a helper function created in DataService like this:

DataService:

```
export class DatsService {
    dataSourceArray = ['initial array data'];
    dataSource = new BehaviorSubject(dataSourceArray);

    updateDataSource = (data) => {
       this.dataSource.next(data)
    }
}
```

In the tabs:

```
 import { DataService } from '././/services/data-service';

 export class IncomeTab implements OnInit{
 
    dataSource: array;

    constructor(
      private dataService: DataService
     ){}
    
      ngOnInit(){
      this.dataService.dataSource.pipe(
       tap((data: array) => this.dataSource = data)  
       )
      }

       updateData = (newArrayData) => {
          this.dataService.updateDataSource(newArrayData);
        // This will cause the observable to be updated so what's inside 
        // the rxjs tap above will run again with the new data
       }


   }
```

In the Tab HTML, use the async pipe to subscribe to the observable:

```
 <h1>{{ dataSource[0]| async }}</h1> 
/* We are subscribing to the observable here in the html using async 
   instead of using subscribe in the .ts file. This way we auto un- 
   subscribe when we're done with the component. */
```

There are other ways to pass data between components so this is just one method. NgRx state management is a best practice if you have more than just a small amount of data working in multiple components across your web app.

Comment: actually came across this solution by accident on my own because I had sibling components that needed to share data - thank you